# File names encoding when running shell-command on Windows XP

Tags: microsoft-windows, files, character-encoding

I faced a problem when pdflatex launched from Emacs couldn't compile files whose name contained Russian characters. The same code worked on Linux, so I suspected that something is wrong with encoding of file name. OS: Windows XP, file system encoding is cp-1251, Emacs:  24.5.1.

I created 2 files:

- D:/Russia.tex
- D:/Россия.tex

Then I tried this:

```
;works fine, produces Russia.pdf
(shell-command "pdflatex D:/Russia.tex")

;doesn't work. TeX error: I can't find file `D:/Россия.tex'
(shell-command "pdflatex D:/Россия.tex")
```

Then I tried to convert the Russian name to cp-1251:

```
;This works, but hard-coded 'cp1251 is bad
(setq file-name (encode-coding-string "D:/Россия.tex" 'cp1251))
(shell-command (concat "pdflatex " file-name))
```

This code has 1 defect - the file system encoding is hard-coded. [Encoding and I/O](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Encoding-and-I_002fO.html) page says that there is a variable `file-name-coding-system` --- "specifies the coding system to use for encoding file names". But it is `nil` for me.

Also the fact that utf-8 code doesn't work is weird as the page says:

> On Windows 2000 and later, Emacs by default uses Unicode APIs to pass
>   file names to the OS, so the value of file-name-coding-system is
>   largely ignored. Lisp applications that need to encode or decode file
>   names on the Lisp level should use utf-8 coding-system when
>   system-type is windows-nt; the conversion of UTF-8 encoded file names
>   to the encoding appropriate for communicating with the OS is performed
>   internally by Emacs.

Maybe this note about utf-8 is not applicable to `shell-command`? How to get the encoding of the file system?

Comment: I have a similar problem on Windows 10... but only affects me when I try, at example, open a file with portuguese accents on daemon mode, so then invalid characters are used. If I open the emacs without a daemon running, just it works... so weird.

Comment: @ManoelVilela It could be easy to fix if we knew, how to get the file system encoding in Emacs. Windows doesn't change: I though Win7 and further have utf-8 file system.

Comment: I solved explicitly setting the `file-name-coding-system` to `latin-1`. Setting to `utf-8` just doesn't works on Windows 10 here. And If I not set explicitly, doesn't works neither because I set the preference-coding system to utf-8 and seems that the emacs choose this encoding after that. My setup now was fixed by this partial file of my init scripts: https://github.com/ryukinix/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/personal/coding-system.el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ~/.emacs we set the variable with fs encoding:

```
(defvar *fs-encoding* 'cp1251)
```

When we need to get the encoded file name, we use function get-file-name:

```
(defun get-file-name (file-name)
  "get file name of the buffer, encode if necessary"
    (when *fs-encoding*
      (shell-quote-argument (encode-coding-string file-name *fs-encoding*)))
    )

(setq file-name (get-file-name "D:/Россия.tex"))
(shell-command (concat "pdflatex " file-name))
```

Answer (score 3):

For windows in ru environment I have the following:

```
(setq default-process-coding-system '(utf-8-dos . cp1251-dos))
```

It let's me process files in russian from emacs using external shell invocations AND I can also use grep, ripgrep and friends to search for russian text.

Comment: Ahha, I'll try it.